# CNAME configuration not working with Heroku app

Tags: heroku, dns

I am using CNAME on my DNS provider site. I am still a bit confused after reading the Heroku documentation. Do I include "www" on Heroku's domain name text field, and do I include that in the "name" text field (second image) in my DNS provider. My domain is not working with the configuration below.

[image]

[image]

Comment: "Do I include "www" on Heroku's domain name text field"—well, do you want to use `www.jhack.tech` or just `jhack.tech`?

Comment: @Chris either one is fine but according to the heroku documentation for CNAME don't I have to put www as the name/host

Comment: What do you mean by "according to the heroku documentation for CNAME don't I have to put www as the name/host"?

Comment: You can not put a CNAME at apex of zone.